# Expressing the "counting of something"

Tags: sentence-construction

We have a process to solve an issue with many different techniques. Each technique produces many results.  I want to mention the number of techniques that were efficient, and use only one sentence. So I have at least three types of count: number of results from each technique, number of techniques, number of techniques that are efficient.

How do I express the number of efficient results?  Can I say this:

- **"We count the number of techniques used for efficient result."**

*(The question originally came from someone else. I was encouraged to re-post my answer to a separate question as a question/answer post.)

Comment: [**This**](http://central-westernma.bbb.org/storage/167/images/facebook%20thumbs%20up.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Grammar Corrections:**  First, the original sentence needs some help with grammar.  In this list (below), the original sentence is first, followed by potential grammar corrections and word variations.  Added spaces make comparing sentences easier:

```
We count   the number of techniques used for         efficient result.  (ORIGINAL)
We count   the number of techniques that have        efficient results. 
We count   the number of techniques that produce     efficient results. 
We count   the           techniques that have        efficient results.
We counted the number of techniques that produced    efficient results. 
We counted               techniques that had         efficient results.
There were three         techniques that produced    efficient results.
We counted each          technique  that produced an efficient result.  
We determined each       technique  that produced an efficient result.
```

**Realistic Example:** For a realistic example, suppose you have these results:

```
An "Efficient Result" is when Efficiency >= 50%.  

Technique   Efficiency   Efficient
   T1          30%
   T2          48%
   T3          59%          *
   T4          66%          *
   T5          91%          *

   Efficient Techniques = {T3, T4, T5} = 3 techniques.
```

Given the above results, suppose you needed to include a step in a process manual:

- Step 3 of the process: "Count the number of techniques that have an Efficiency >= 50%"

If you needed to report to management, you might say this in an email:

- There were 3 techniques that had efficient results: T3, T4, and T5.
  (Efficiency >= 50%)